# Symbol not found when importing cv2

Tags: python, macos, opencv, symbol-not-found

I am attempting to import cv2 using python. When I use the import cv2 function in jupyter notebook I get a string of code indicating that the symbol is not found and therefore cv2 cannot be imported. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KObkI.png)

I have tried updating opencv code using various code in my terminal including pip install opencv-python in both my terminal and my jupyter environment. Each time it said that the opencv is installed and that both environments are running on anaconda3 as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Either upgrade your OS-X or install an older version of OpenCV (and python)